# Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I currently have Accounts Table, Roles Table and AccountRoles Table which store the account id and roleid for the relation. I am trying to get the Role name from the Roles Table by checking the AccountRoles Table for the ID that is tagged to the account ID.

Below is my controller code:

```
$accounts = Account::with('roles')->where('acc_clinicID', '=', $_SESSION['clinic_ID'])->get();
```

I tried dd($accounts) and I am able to get the roleName from the relation as attached in the image.
[dd($accounts) result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2lJI.png)

However when I do a dd($accounts->roles->roleName) I got the error: Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance.

Below is my Model of the tables involved:

Account.php

```
 public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role');
    }
```

Role.php

```
public function accounts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Account');
    }
```

Please kindly enlightened me on where have I done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It's because your relation contains an array. You have to loop through your roles relation and then access the role name

Comment: `$accounts` is a Collection ... `get` on the Builder always returns a Collection

Comment: Yes I am trying to display a list of the accounts with the role the account is tagged in a datatable hence I use `get` to return a collection

Comment: @AhmadKarimi i tried `$account->roles->roleName` at my front end in my foreach loop it gives an error of `Property [roleName] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: I tried `$account->roles` in my front end I am able to get these data on my each row of datatable `[{"roleID":1,"roleName":"Admin","created_at":"2021-03-25T05:57:54.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-25T05:57:54.000000Z","pivot":{"account_accountID":1,"role_roleID":1}}]`

Answer (score 0):

@junmingyeo98 Can you please change your relation function in Account.php from belongsToMany to belongsTo.

Comment: I have changed as suggested however I am getting this error now 

`Trying to get property 'roleName' of non-object`

Comment: you can also change you query like below,  $accounts = Account::with('roles')->where('acc_clinicID', \Session::get('clinic_ID'))->get();

Comment: Hi, I have tried what you have suggested and its the same results.

Comment: Hello @junmingyeo98 ,i have just checked your dd result and found that roles come in array so i hope you are trying to access inside foerach loop.
Thanks :)

Comment: Hi I did include a foreach loop for this as shown below, however once I add in `$account->roles->roleName` into my `$account->roles` there is the property error shown. `@foreach($accounts as $account)
<tr id="{{ $account->{'accountID'} }}">
<td></td>
<td>{{ $account->{'name'} }}</td>
<td>{{ $account->{'username'} }}</td>
<td>{{ $account->{'email'} }}</td>
<td>{{ $account->{'phoneNo'} }}</td>
<td>{{ $account->roles }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach`

Comment: Hello can you please try this one. @foreach($accounts as $account) <tr id="{{ $account->{'accountID'} }}"> <td></td> <td>{{ $account->{'name'} }}</td> <td>{{ $account->{'username'} }}</td> <td>{{ $account->{'email'} }}</td> <td>{{ $account->{'phoneNo'} }}</td> <td>@foreach($account->roles as $roles)<span>{{ $roles->roleName }} ,</span>@endforeach </td></tr> @endforeach

Comment: Hi it works! Would you mind explaining the answer on using another foreach loop inside the td?